# AngularJS: ui-select not showing on view

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have tried every possible outcome. But can't get this to work. I am new to web-development, please help out.

I pulled ui-select from github. Added the necessary files (CSS & jS) into my `index` but still can't get it working. I have read the docs as well. I have also `ngSanitize` running.

A simple field like this won't appear.

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="bootstrap">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a person in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="item in people | filter: $select.search">
    <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    <small ng-bind-html="item.email | highlight: $select.search"></small>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: seems ok to me. do you have any error in the console? How do you fetch people?

Comment: @koox00 hi! from a json file. But the field itself `<ui-select-match>` is not apearing on my browser. I have tried both chrome and firefox

Comment: can you post also your controller?

Answer (score 2):

Created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uqKlpv6F54NwO18K4FVP?p=preview) with your code and it works fine!
Assuming your controller is setup correctly and you inject the `ui.select` module the code above should work.

Keep in mind that you should load and inject the `ng-sanitize` module also so that the [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive can be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you version of bootstrap

You are using `ui-select` which need bootstrap `0.14.x`

See this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/33134346/4406065